# Trouble with rspec and expect change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using rspec to test a Ruby terminal app. I can't seem to figure out to test for a change in a hash

I'm still trying to wrap my head around testing in general, so it's quite possible I'm misunderstanding multiple things in regards to testing.

I'm trying to test that when a charge is added to an instance of Account but the charge exceeds the accounts limit. The balance on the account doesn't change.

```
class Account
  def apply_charge(card_holder_name, charge)
    charge       = int_dollar_input(charge)
    account      = find_account_by_card_holder(card_holder_name) 
    temp_balance = account[:balance] + charge

    account[:balance] = account[:balance] + charge if temp_balance < account[:limit]
  end
end

describe "Adding a charge to an account" do
  context "GIVEN a charge amount that exceeds the account limit" do

    let(:account)     { subject.add_account("William", 5454545454545454,'$1000') }

    it "will do nothing" do
      expect(subject.apply_charge('William', '$1200')).
        to_not change {account[:balance]} 
    end
  end
end
```

account is a array of hash(s)

```
account.inspect = [{:card_holder_name=>"William", :card_number=>5454545454545454, :limit=>1000, :balance=>0}]
```

> 1) Account Adding a charge to an account GIVEN a charge amount that
>   exceeds the account limit will do nothing
>        Failure/Error:
>          expect(subject.apply_charge('William', '$1200')).
>            to_not change {account[:balance]}
>
> ```
>    expected `account[:balance]` not to have changed, but was not given a block
>  # ./spec/account_spec.rb:46:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expect needs to be in a block: `expect { subject.apply_charge('William', '$1200') }.to.....`